# .htaccess rule to skip folder name from entire urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost

My project name is funfeesa and all client side pages are contains in "client" folder. But I want to access then without to write client folder in the url.
just like below:

```
localhost/funfeesa/index.php
```

I have tried many rules in `.htaccess` file but nothing is working fine.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
#prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*


#follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^funfeesa/index.php(.+)?$ funfeesa/client/index.php/$1
```

Try to access your .htaccess file as above

Still if it doesn't work try by removing index.php from above rules but I think It should work :)

Comment: thankyou so much for quick help.
But its not working even tried without index.php
getting Object not found! when i am accessing 
localhost/funfeesa/index.php

Comment: @NafisaKanwal try by removing `Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*` This lines

Comment: i did now its redirecting to http://localhost/client/funfeesa/index.php
it start appending 'client' folder before the project folder name